# Background image/color not visible in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background, background-image

I am using this scheme for desktop background. For the homepage I am using the body tag with the class "gd", so the background is given on the home page. The given css is working fine in FF,Chrome,Safari but I am having problem hacking it for IE.

```
body{  
color:#0066cc;  
background:white;  
padding-top:20px;  
min-width:500px;  
height:100%;  
}
```

and this style for the main page

```
body.gd{  
background:#87ceeb url("../images/bg.jpg") bottom center no-repeat !important;  
background-color:#87ceeb !important;  /*P.S. This line just added for testing */  
}
```

The last line in .gd class is not even showing the background color, it might be possibility that IE is not accepting the body tag with **gd** class, but in this class how may overcome this behaviour.

> P.S. I am using IE9,IE8 and IE7. Three of them are not showing.

Comment: Have you tried removing the quotes around `"../images/bg.jpg"` ? I.e. just using: `url(../images/bg.jpg)`

Comment: Yeah @Chris, I've removed the quotes as well. It is still not working.

Comment: "background: white;" should be "background-color: white;". You don't need that !important on body.gd because body.gd is already more specific (because of the .gd class).

Comment: I've just added !important for testing (it might be worth ;-) ). It is working fine w/o the !important tag in all browsers.

Comment: Using a Developer's Tool, can you change the color? What if you invert and make that other color default? Have you tried changing the html tag background-color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help @7th [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189004/background-image-color-not-visible-in-ie#comment19668817_14189004).
The problem here is with the html tag.

Which was before

```
html{  
background-color:#ffffff;  
zoom:1;  
**background-color:transparent\9;**  
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffffffff, endColorstr=#ffffffff)";  
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffffffff, endColorstr=#ffffffff);  
padding:0;  
margin:0;  
}
```

And After

```
html{  
background-color:#ffffff;  
padding:0;  
margin:0;  
}
```

And then I realized that **background-color:transparent** was making error. I didn't know why IE was inheriting it into background, even I've added seperate style definition for the body tag. Any way, Now, It is working fine for me.

> **P.S. Explanation on this will be much appreciated**

Comment: @7th, your guess might be true. But I've told that the background properties in the Css was causing problem. It has fixed now.